How can I replicate rows in R based on the values of another row?
I am wondering how to write a function to replicate rows based on the value within a column, e.g. if there is a difference of > +-0.1 between one row and the next, that row is replicated so that the row value increases/decreases linearly in increments of 0.1 from the first value to the last.
I have a dataset with the following format
#produce dataset
df <- data.frame(site = c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5), sample = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
 depth =c(0.4,0.5,1.1,1.5,1.7,1.4,2.2), cover=c(80,90,70,80,60,50,80))


   site sample depth cover
1     5      1   0.4    80
2     5      2   0.5    90
3     5      3   1.1    70
4     5      4   1.5    80
5     5      5   1.7    60
6     5      6   1.4    50
7     5      7   2.2    60

So i am looking to replicate columns so that the depth column increases/decreases in 0.1 intervals.
The expanded dataset would therefore look as follows
   Site Sample Depth Cover
1     5    1.0   0.4    80
2     5    2.0   0.5    90
3     5    2.1   0.6    90
4     5    2.2   0.7    90
5     5    2.3   0.8    90
6     5    2.4   0.9    90
7     5    2.5   1.0    90
8     5    3.0   1.1    70
9     5    3.1   1.2    70
10    5    3.2   1.3    70
11    5    3.3   1.4    70
12    5    4.0   1.5    80
13    5    4.1   1.6    80
14    5    5.0   1.7    60
15    5    6.0   1.6    50
16    5    6.1   1.5    50
17    5    6.2   1.4    50
18    5    7.0   1.5    60
19    5    7.1   1.6    60
20    5    7.2   1.7    60
21    5    7.3   1.8    60
22    5    7.4   1.9    60
23    5    7.5   2.0    60
24    5    7.6   2.1    60
25    5    7.7   2.2    60

Note that on line 14 the depth decreases before increasing again.
Apologies if this sort of question has been answered elsewhere but I could not find anything with this particular use case and I am not great at writing functions.
Would really appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.
Thanks
EDIT*************************************
So I ran both the code posted below and both work but when applied to full dataset I run into a problem with the transition from one site to the next. I probably should have included multiple sites in my sample data when framing my question, apologies.
I have included a new sample dataset below
df = structure(list(site = c("one", "one", "one", "one", "two", "two", 
                        "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", 
"two"), sample = c(1L, 
                                                                                     
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), depth = c(0.3, 
                                                                                                                                                
1.3, 1.6, 2.9, 0.5, 1.5, 2.7, 3.2, 3.8, 4.1, 4.4, 4.7, 5.2), 
               cover = c(0L, 35L, 60L, 10L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 10L, 
0L, 
                         5L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA, -13L))

which when run gives the following dataset
   site sample depth cover
1   one      1   0.3     0
2   one      2   1.3    35
3   one      3   1.6    60
4   one      4   2.9    10
5   two      1   0.5     5
6   two      2   1.5     2
7   two      3   2.7     0
8   two      4   3.2    20
9   two      5   3.8     0
10  two      6   4.1    10
11  two      7   4.4     0
12  two      8   4.7     5
13  two      9   5.2     0

And then applying one of the solutions below
# fills NA's in sample
fill_sample_na <- function(sample, step = 0.1) {
  g <- na.locf0(sample)
  ave(g, g, FUN = function(x) seq(x[1], length = length(x), by = step))
}

newdf = df %>%
  mutate(nd = round(abs(depth - dplyr::lag(depth)) / 0.1 - 1), .by = 
site) %>%
  group_by(site, row = row_number()) %>%
  group_modify(~ if (!is.na(.x$nd) && .x$nd > 0) 
     add_row(.x, sample = rep(NA, .x$nd), .before = TRUE) else .x
  ) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(sample = fill_sample_na(sample), depth = na.approx(depth),
    cover = na.locf0(cover), .by = site) %>%
  select(-row, -nd) %>%
  data.frame

provides the following dataset
newdf
   site sample depth cover .by
1   one    1.0   0.3     0 one
2   one    1.1   0.4     0 one
3   one    1.2   0.5     0 one
4   one    1.3   0.6     0 one
5   one    1.4   0.7     0 one
6   one    1.5   0.8     0 one
7   one    1.6   0.9     0 one
8   one    1.7   1.0     0 one
9   one    1.8   1.1     0 one
10  one    1.9   1.2     0 one
11  one    2.0   1.3    35 one
12  one    2.1   1.4    35 one
13  one    2.2   1.5    35 one
14  one    3.0   1.6    60 one
15  one    3.1   1.7    60 one
16  one    3.2   1.8    60 one
17  one    3.3   1.9    60 one
18  one    3.4   2.0    60 one
19  one    3.5   2.1    60 one
20  one    3.6   2.2    60 one
21  one    3.7   2.3    60 one
22  one    3.8   2.4    60 one
23  one    3.9   2.5    60 one
24  one    4.0   2.6    60 one
25  one    4.1   2.7    60 one
26  one    4.2   2.8    60 one
27  one    4.0   2.9    10 one
28  two    4.1   2.8    10 two
29  two    4.2   2.7    10 two
30  two    4.3   2.6    10 two
31  two    4.4   2.5    10 two
32  two    4.5   2.4    10 two
33  two    4.6   2.3    10 two
34  two    4.7   2.2    10 two
35  two    4.8   2.1    10 two
36  two    4.9   2.0    10 two
37  two    5.0   1.9    10 two
38  two    5.1   1.8    10 two
39  two    5.2   1.7    10 two
40  two    5.3   1.6    10 two
41  two    5.4   1.5    10 two
42  two    5.5   1.4    10 two
43  two    5.6   1.3    10 two
44  two    5.7   1.2    10 two
45  two    5.8   1.1    10 two
46  two    5.9   1.0    10 two
47  two    6.0   0.9    10 two
48  two    6.1   0.8    10 two
49  two    6.2   0.7    10 two
50  two    6.3   0.6    10 two
51  two    2.0   0.5     5 two
52  two    2.1   0.6     5 two
53  two    2.2   0.7     5 two
54  two    2.3   0.8     5 two
55  two    2.4   0.9     5 two
56  two    2.5   1.0     5 two
57  two    2.6   1.1     5 two
58  two    2.7   1.2     5 two
59  two    2.8   1.3     5 two
60  two    2.9   1.4     5 two
61  two    2.3   1.5     2 two
62  two    2.4   1.6     2 two
63  two    2.5   1.7     2 two
64  two    2.6   1.8     2 two
65  two    2.7   1.9     2 two
66  two    2.8   2.0     2 two
67  two    2.9   2.1     2 two
68  two    3.0   2.2     2 two
69  two    3.1   2.3     2 two
70  two    3.2   2.4     2 two
71  two    3.3   2.5     2 two
72  two    3.4   2.6     2 two
73  two    4.3   2.7     0 two
74  two    4.4   2.8     0 two
75  two    4.5   2.9     0 two
76  two    4.6   3.0     0 two
77  two    4.7   3.1     0 two
78  two    6.4   3.2    20 two
79  two    6.5   3.3    20 two
80  two    6.6   3.4    20 two
81  two    6.7   3.5    20 two
82  two    6.8   3.6    20 two
83  two    6.9   3.7    20 two
84  two    5.0   3.8     0 two
85  two    5.1   3.9     0 two
86  two    5.2   4.0     0 two
87  two    6.0   4.1    10 two
88  two    6.1   4.2    10 two
89  two    6.2   4.3    10 two
90  two    7.0   4.4     0 two
91  two    7.1   4.5     0 two
92  two    7.2   4.6     0 two
93  two    8.0   4.7     5 two
94  two    8.1   4.8     5 two
95  two    8.2   4.9     5 two
96  two    8.3   5.0     5 two
97  two    8.4   5.1     5 two
98  two    9.0   5.2     0 two

On line 28 we transition from site one to site two, but instead of starting at the first depth (0.5), the code carries on from site one and decreases incrementally from the last depth of the previous site until reaching the the "starting" depth of site two. The same is true for the sample number.
This is the case for both of the solutions posted below. Again, I know these solutions worked for the sample dataset provided so apologies, but I would very much appreciate if there was a solution to this problem without having to first subset data by site.

An iterative solution:
df_add <- function(data, increment=0.1) {
  df <- data[1,]
  df['sample'] <- as.character(df['sample']) # Added after OP edit
  k <- 1 / increment
  for(i in 2:nrow(data)) {
    d1 <- data[i-1, 'depth'] * k
    d2 <- data[i, 'depth'] * k
    s1 <- data[i-1, 'site']   # Added
    s2 <- data[i, 'site']     # Added
    if(s1==s2 & abs(d2 - d1) > 1) {   # Added `s1==s2 & `
      depth <- (seq(d1, d2) / k)
      depth <- depth[2:(length(depth) - 1)]
      df <- rbind(df, 
                  data.frame(site=s1,
                             sample=paste(data[i-1, 'sample'], 
                                     seq_along(depth), sep="."),
                             depth=depth,
                             cover=data[i-1, 'cover']
                  )
      )
    }
    df <- rbind(df, data[i,])
  }
  df
}

(newdf <- df_add(df2))


    site sample depth cover
1    one      1   0.3     0
2    one    1.1   0.4     0
3    one    1.2   0.5     0
4    one    1.3   0.6     0
5    one    1.4   0.7     0
6    one    1.5   0.8     0
7    one    1.6   0.9     0
8    one    1.7   1.0     0
9    one    1.8   1.1     0
10   one    1.9   1.2     0
21   one      2   1.3    35
11   one    2.1   1.4    35
22   one    2.2   1.5    35
31   one      3   1.6    60
13   one    3.1   1.7    60
23   one    3.2   1.8    60
32   one    3.3   1.9    60
41   one    3.4   2.0    60
51   one    3.5   2.1    60
61   one    3.6   2.2    60
71   one    3.7   2.3    60
81   one    3.8   2.4    60
91   one    3.9   2.5    60
101  one   3.10   2.6    60
111  one   3.11   2.7    60
12   one   3.12   2.8    60
42   one      4   2.9    10
52   two      1   0.5     5
14   two    1.1   0.6     5
24   two    1.2   0.7     5
33   two    1.3   0.8     5
43   two    1.4   0.9     5
53   two    1.5   1.0     5
62   two    1.6   1.1     5
72   two    1.7   1.2     5
82   two    1.8   1.3     5
92   two    1.9   1.4     5
63   two      2   1.5     2
15   two    2.1   1.6     2
25   two    2.2   1.7     2
34   two    2.3   1.8     2
44   two    2.4   1.9     2
54   two    2.5   2.0     2
64   two    2.6   2.1     2
73   two    2.7   2.2     2
83   two    2.8   2.3     2
93   two    2.9   2.4     2
102  two   2.10   2.5     2
112  two   2.11   2.6     2
74   two      3   2.7     0
16   two    3.1   2.8     0
26   two    3.2   2.9     0
35   two    3.3   3.0     0
45   two    3.4   3.1     0
84   two      4   3.2    20
17   two    4.1   3.3    20
27   two    4.2   3.4    20
36   two    4.3   3.5    20
46   two    4.4   3.6    20
55   two    4.5   3.7    20
94   two      5   3.8     0
18   two    5.1   3.9     0
28   two    5.2   4.0     0
103  two      6   4.1    10
19   two    6.1   4.2    10
29   two    6.2   4.3    10
113  two      7   4.4     0
110  two    7.1   4.5     0
210  two    7.2   4.6     0
121  two      8   4.7     5
114  two    8.1   4.8     5
211  two    8.2   4.9     5
37   two    8.3   5.0     5
47   two    8.4   5.1     5
131  two      9   5.2     0

You can also change the value to increment:
df_add(df, increment=0.05)


     site sample depth cover
1     one   1.00  0.30     0
2     one   1.10  0.35     0
3     one   1.20  0.40     0
4     one   1.30  0.45     0
5     one   1.40  0.50     0
6     one   1.50  0.55     0 
...


Thanks very much for the solution, I have updated my original post with a follow up.

OK - see my edit.

That works perfectly. Thanks again!

You can use reframe + seq like below
df %>%
  mutate(p = lead(depth, default = last(depth) + 0.1)) %>%
  reframe(
    depth = first(seq(depth, p, 0.1 * (2 * (depth <= p) - 1)), -1),
    .by = c(site, sample, cover)
  ) %>%
  select(names(df)) %>%
  mutate(sample = str_c(sample, ".", 0:(n() - 1)), .by = c(site, sample))

which gives
   site sample depth cover
1   one    1.0   0.3     0
2   one    1.1   0.4     0
3   one    1.2   0.5     0
4   one    1.3   0.6     0
5   one    1.4   0.7     0
6   one    1.5   0.8     0
7   one    1.6   0.9     0
8   one    1.7   1.0     0
9   one    1.8   1.1     0
10  one    1.9   1.2     0
11  one    2.0   1.3    35
12  one    2.1   1.4    35
13  one    2.2   1.5    35
14  one    3.0   1.6    60
15  one    3.1   1.7    60
16  one    3.2   1.8    60
17  one    3.3   1.9    60
18  one    3.4   2.0    60
19  one    3.5   2.1    60
20  one    3.6   2.2    60
21  one    3.7   2.3    60
22  one    3.8   2.4    60
23  one    3.9   2.5    60
24  one   3.10   2.6    60
25  one   3.11   2.7    60
26  one   3.12   2.8    60
27  one    4.0   2.9    10
28  one    4.1   2.8    10
29  one    4.2   2.7    10
30  one    4.3   2.6    10
31  one    4.4   2.5    10
32  one    4.5   2.4    10
33  one    4.6   2.3    10
34  one    4.7   2.2    10
35  one    4.8   2.1    10
36  one    4.9   2.0    10
37  one   4.10   1.9    10
38  one   4.11   1.8    10
39  one   4.12   1.7    10
40  one   4.13   1.6    10
41  one   4.14   1.5    10
42  one   4.15   1.4    10
43  one   4.16   1.3    10
44  one   4.17   1.2    10
45  one   4.18   1.1    10
46  one   4.19   1.0    10
47  one   4.20   0.9    10
48  one   4.21   0.8    10
49  one   4.22   0.7    10
50  one   4.23   0.6    10
51  two    1.0   0.5     5
52  two    1.1   0.6     5
53  two    1.2   0.7     5
54  two    1.3   0.8     5
55  two    1.4   0.9     5
56  two    1.5   1.0     5
57  two    1.6   1.1     5
58  two    1.7   1.2     5
59  two    1.8   1.3     5
60  two    1.9   1.4     5
61  two    2.0   1.5     2
62  two    2.1   1.6     2
63  two    2.2   1.7     2
64  two    2.3   1.8     2
65  two    2.4   1.9     2
66  two    2.5   2.0     2
67  two    2.6   2.1     2
68  two    2.7   2.2     2
69  two    2.8   2.3     2
70  two    2.9   2.4     2
71  two   2.10   2.5     2
72  two   2.11   2.6     2
73  two    3.0   2.7     0
74  two    3.1   2.8     0
75  two    3.2   2.9     0
76  two    3.3   3.0     0
77  two    3.4   3.1     0
78  two    4.0   3.2    20
79  two    4.1   3.3    20
80  two    4.2   3.4    20
81  two    4.3   3.5    20
82  two    4.4   3.6    20
83  two    4.5   3.7    20
84  two    5.0   3.8     0
85  two    5.1   3.9     0
86  two    5.2   4.0     0
87  two    6.0   4.1    10
88  two    6.1   4.2    10
89  two    6.2   4.3    10
90  two    7.0   4.4     0
91  two    7.1   4.5     0
92  two    7.2   4.6     0
93  two    8.0   4.7     5
94  two    8.1   4.8     5
95  two    8.2   4.9     5
96  two    8.3   5.0     5
97  two    8.4   5.1     5
98  two    9.0   5.2     0

